# how to make php escape brackets in heredoc?

Tags: php

I want to escape brackets in heredoc (in php),
for example,

```
$str = <<<EOD    
hello <hello inside>
EOD;
```

but when i echo this string, i just get "hello" as output

Comment: Could you please clarify your question? :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has nothing to do with PHP really. It's your browser interpreting `<hello inside>` as a tag.

I'm afraid there is no automatic way of turning this into HTML elements inside heredoc; you'd have to do a  `htmlspecialchars();` on the whole string, or use HTML entities:

```
$str = <<<EOD    
hello &lt;hello inside&gt;
EOD;
```

Answer (score 2):

I would have just left this as a comment to Pekka's answer, but you can't format comments this way.  You can always treat HEREDOC/NOWDOC blocks just like strings (as long as nothing follows the closing identifier on that line), so this is perfectly valid:

```
$str = htmlentities(<<< EOD
hello <hello inside>
EOD
);
```

and is the same as:

```
$str = <<< EOD
hello <hello inside>
EOD;
$str = htmlentities($str);
```